# How do I remove this selected shape?

Tags: c++, qt

So I have created a shape using items and then added those items to a QGraphicsItemGroup. The group is set with the flags movable and selectable. My issue is I cannot find a method that allows me to remove the group and all the items in it when it is selected.

[image]

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#selectionChanged

Comment: What is your problem, more specifically? Where are you stuck when trying to do this?

Comment: So I have a delete button that is located on in the GUI that says "Delete". When an image is selected and this button is pressed I want the function to remove the selected item from the scene.

Comment: ... so just delete it? What is th issue, exactly? You can get currently selected items from scene when you handle the button press, and then you can just delete them. No need for that signal linked above, even.

Comment: Oh so within the mousePressEvent I can get the currentlySelected items and remove them?